# BETWEEN SQL - why is there a gap lock?

Tags: mysql, innodb, between, clustered-index, rowlocking

```
CREATE TABLE justpk
(
    A INT,
    B INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (A)
);

INSERT INTO justpk (A, B) VALUES (1, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1);
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 1 |    1 |
| 4 |    1 |
| 5 |    1 |
+---+------+
```

Session1:

```
begin;
SELECT * FROM justpk WHERE A BETWEEN 1 AND 5 FOR UPDATE;
```

In another random session:

```
INSERT INTO lockingreads.justpk (A, B) VALUES (0, 1); # allowed
UPDATE lockingreads.justpk SET B = 2 WHERE A = 1; # blocked
INSERT INTO lockingreads.justpk (A, B) VALUES (2, 1); # blocked
INSERT INTO lockingreads.justpk (A, B) VALUES (3, 1); # blocked
UPDATE lockingreads.justpk SET B = 2 WHERE A = 4; # blocked
UPDATE lockingreads.justpk SET B = 2 WHERE A = 5; # blocked
INSERT INTO lockingreads.justpk (A, B) VALUES (6, 1); # blocked // what?
```

why is there a **gap lock after 5** if a = 6 would not be included in the "between" condition?

Comment: I suspect this is related to the structure of the B-tree.

Comment: I think InnoDB does gap locking when there is some edge case where it would be too difficult to be more specific.  Live with it.

Comment: hi @Rick James, I have studied some gap locking, and I think I have come to the conclusion that you yourself say, MYSQL IS NOT "PREDICTABLE" to tell us when it will do gap locking. I feel the most important thing is to JUST UNDERSTAND THAT THESE LOCKS EXIST TO AVOID INSERTs and nothing else and let mysql do it for us, right?

Comment: hi, yes @Barmar I think so, I guess you have to look at a lot of details for that, although I'm believing that even so mysql doesn't stop surprising in gap locks and we have to deal with it as Rick James says.

Comment: @Daniel - Good.  I don't know about "and nothing else" -- possibly Updates and Deletes are blocked in some situations.  As for the BTree -- I would expect that to be at a lower level, hence not relevant.  (But I am guessing.)

Comment: "and nothing else" @Rick James I mean the important thing is to KNOW that it avoids INSERTs and "it is not necessary" to know all possible cases of gap locking (we see how MySQL takes edge cases not predictable), I understand that obviously there will be locks for DELETE/UPDATE as well.